# How do I rotate then move an element up, down, left or right based on an array of directions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, execution

[GitHub Pages](https://malaxor.github.io/cow-grazer/)

[Repo](https://github.com/Malaxor/cow-grazer)

I'm trying to move a cow (10px per move) up (North), down (South), left (West) and right (East) in a field. After I've collected an array of cardinal directions, I setting the cow's style.left and style.up and rotating it based on the directions in the array.

How do I first make the cow rotate in the direction before moving in it, then turing in another direction before moving in it? Right now, let's say there are 3 North directions in the array: the cow will move the whole 30px instead of the 10px per move. If there are East and South directions, the cow won't rotate East and move 10px East, then rotate South and move 10px South. It's important that the cow receive an array of directions before rotating and moving.

```
const cow = {
   directions: ['North', 'East'],
   addDirection(direction) {
      this.directions.push(direction);
   }
};

let num = 0; // will increment or decrement by 90 or 180
let key = null; // keep track of keys to determine how much to increment or decrement
cow.directions.forEach(direction => {
   switch(direction) {
      case 'North':
         if(!key) {
            cowEl.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
         }
         else if(key === 'East') {
            num -= 90;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         else if(key === 'West') {
            num += 90;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         else if(key === 'South') {
            num -= 180;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         key = direction; // North
         // setTimeout(() => cowEl.style.top = parseInt(cowEl.style.top) - moveBy + 'px', 1000);
         cowEl.style.top = parseInt(cowEl.style.top) - moveBy + 'px';
      break;

      case 'East':
         if(!key || key === 'North') {
            num += 90;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         else if(key === 'South') {
            num -= 90;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         else if(key === 'West') {
            num -= 180;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         key = direction; // East
         // setTimeout(() => cowEl.style.left = parseInt(cowEl.style.left) + moveBy + 'px', 2000);
         cowEl.style.left = parseInt(cowEl.style.left) + moveBy + 'px';
      break;

      case 'South':
         if(!key || key === 'North') {
            num += 180;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         else if(key === 'East') {
            num += 90;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }   
         else if(key === 'West') {
            num -= 90;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         key = direction; // South
         cowEl.style.top = parseInt(cowEl.style.top) + moveBy + 'px';
      break;

      case 'West':
         if(!key || key === 'North') {
            num -= 90;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         else if(key === 'South') {
            num += 90;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         else if(key === 'East') {
            num += 180;
            cowEl.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`;
         }
         key = direction; // West
         cowEl.style.left = parseInt(cowEl.style.left) - moveBy + 'px';
      break;
   }   
});
```

Comment: please add your relevant code at least

Comment: Are you using CSS animations or Javascript + timings? Please read [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as we'll only be guessing at a solution if we can't see how you are trying to implement this.

Comment: I've added the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to notate directions in coding. Here is how you should notate directions:

1. North `{x:0, y:1}`
2. South `{x:0, y:-1}`
3. East `{x:1, y:0}`
4. West `{x:-1, y:0}`

I don't know about the exact ones but this is how I usually do it.
Now if you need to make an array of specific directions:
example: [North, East, South, North, West]
You will do it using those notations like this:
`[{x:0, y:1}, {x:1, y:0}, {x:0, y:-1}, {x:0, y:1}, {x:-1, y:0}]`

Once you have the array you can easily use the `array.forEach()` function to loop through all the directions and call a function. Inside the loop you can make an if else case which will help you rotate the cow as well as moving it in those specific directions.
Hope this answer helps you in making the logic!
If yes, then upvote this answer to help others in finding this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the notations in my first answer you just have the specific X and Y values to the current coordinates of the cow to make it move.
For example: Let the current coordinates of the cow be `{x:10, y:9}`
then to make it go north add the notation values of north to the coordinates.
The notation for north is `{x:0, y:1}`
adding 0 to x will give x = 10,
and adding 1 to y will give y = 10.
So now the cow has moved to the north! With the new coordinates `{x:10, y:10}`